# Not able to set Adcontrol TestMode property value in WP7 app

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone-7.1.1

I have added AdControl control to my windows phone application. In Xaml view designer I could see the ad preview. But when I run it in my phone I see a black box and nothing in it.

I tried to set TestMode property but there is no such static or non static method available for AdControl .

I have cross checked Applicationid and AdControlId.All the capabilities are added..

```
 <UI:AdControl x:Name="AdBox" IsAutoCollapseEnabled="True"    IsAutoRefreshEnabled="True" Visibility="Visible" Margin="-12,0,-12,0" Height = "80"  ApplicationId="ca1215264283-ba59-" AdUnitId="125679" />
```

Any fix to this issue ? Or we can ignore it and works directly once the app is published ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out this one. if there is no advertiser willing to bid on an impression with a positive dollar value then no ad is displayed.